# Sending formData with ReactJS to Express API and taking a responding JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jsx

Trying to get the ReactJS frontend to send in a username and password from a form to my express api via a proxy, and then have the app.post in the API return a JSON file of a user id. Proxy connection works fine, but when I send the username and password states to the API, it comes through as 'undefined' on the other end. Not sure if it's an issue with my handlers, event code/forms, or my express API.

ReactJS:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../public/styles/App.css'
import Header from "./header.js"

var recID = []

export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            username: "",
            password: "",
            user: []
        }

        this.checkLogin = this.checkLogin.bind(this)
        this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this)
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleUsernameChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({username: e.target.value});
    }

    handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({password: e.target.value});
    }

    checkLogin(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch('/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({"user": this.state.username, "pass": this.state.password}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user_id => this.setState({user: user_id}))
        recID = recID.concat(this.state.user)
        if (recID.length == 6) {
            this.setState({isLoggedIn: true})
        }
    }

    loginScreen() {
        return(   
            <div style={{border:"none"}}>
                <div style={{background:"white"}}>
                <br></br>
                    <center><Header /></center>
                <br></br>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <div style={{background:"white"}}>
                <center><form onSubmit={e => this.checkLogin(e)}>
                    <br></br>
                    Username: <br></br>
                    <input type = "text" name= "username" onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}></input>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    Password: <br></br>
                    <input type = "text" name = "password" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}></input>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Log-in"></input>
                    <br></br>
                </form></center>
                <br></br>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

    success() {
        return (
            <div>
              <p>TEST</p>
              {this.state.user && this.state.user.map(us => <div key={us.user_id}> {us.user_id} </div>)}
            </div>
          )
    }

    render() {
            if (this.state.isLoggedIn == true) {
                return (
                    this.success()
                )
            }
            else {
                return (
                    this.loginScreen()
                )
            }
    }
}
```

Relevant NodeJS API Code:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const users = require('./modules/user_management.js')

const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.post("/api/login", async(req, res) => {
    const id = await users.login(req.body.user, req.body.pass)
    console.log(id)
    res.json(id)
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`))
```

Comment: So presumably you have configured your Express app to be able to handle JSON requests? It's not something that works out the box.

Comment: I have a body parser, that's about it. Is there something else I need for express to work with JSON requests?

Comment: You would need to show your configuration to make sure it's correct. If that all looks good then the culprit maybe an incorrectly configured Proxy (`POST` parameters may not be getting preserved).

Comment: console.log shows that the express is receiving an empty array from the body, so the issue lies somewhere in the ReactJS code, not properly passing on the states into a JSON array.

Comment: Doesn't help that my console.log commands won't work with ReactJS.

Comment: wrong, I can pretty much guarantee, based on the React code you've shown, the JSON data will be in the request going to the server (you can verify this by inspecting the network request in the Browser Dev tools). Again, I'll ask if you can include your body parser configuration code.

Comment: Added an edit that shows the body-parser requirement and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Node.js file, make sure to add:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

as it is currently only set up to parse urlencoded input.

Also, if that doesn't work, try removing the JSON.stringify in the fetch function, as I am not sure if that is necessary since you are already using body-parser.

EDIT - Nevermind, I was wrong about this. The JSON.stringify should be left in the original fetch call.

If neither of those two work, let me know and I'd be happy to come up with some additional suggestions.

Cheers,
Gabe

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185244/discussion-on-answer-by-gabor-szekely-sending-formdata-with-reactjs-to-express-a).